# Django, How can I check the choicefield value and checked the checkbox of MultipleChoiceField?

Tags: django

For example, we can use getelementbyid to get the value,
and then set checked=true, to check the checkbox

But how can I do this in Django?

Sorry for my poor english

Comment: I have solved this problem by using the template and  js anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial values like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    choices = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=(
            ('choice_1', 'Choice 1'), ('choice_2', 'Choice 2'))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choicefield_name'].initial = ['choice_1', 'choice_2']
```